# Laravel 5 SQL join 3 tables but return null

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have 3 tables.

1. Name: **Directory**
   [image]
2. Name: **Directory_relations**
   [image]
3. Name: **Videos**

   [image]

My problem is when I want join 3 tables. Because when I join Directory with Directory_relations its display correct but only folders, but when I join vidoes, display nothing. Is any possible to display all of this.

In code below miss ROW In folder 3 with VIDEO_ID.

```
array:1 [▼
      0 => array:9 [▼
        "id" => "4"
        "video_id" => "0"
        "directory_id" => "4"
        "parent_id" => "0"
        "created_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
        "name" => "Folder2"
        "user_id" => "265"
        "children" => array:2 [▼
          0 => array:9 [▼
            "id" => "5"
            "video_id" => "0"
            "directory_id" => "5"
            "parent_id" => "4"
            "created_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
            "updated_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
            "name" => "Folder3"
            "user_id" => "265"
            "children" => array:1 [▼
              0 => array:8 [▼
                "id" => "7"
                "video_id" => "0"
                "directory_id" => "7"
                "parent_id" => "5"
                "created_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
                "updated_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
                "name" => "Folder33"
                "user_id" => "265"
              ]
            ]
          ]
          1 => array:8 [▼
            "id" => "6"
            "video_id" => "0"
            "directory_id" => "6"
            "parent_id" => "4"
            "created_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
            "updated_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
            "name" => "Folder22"
            "user_id" => "265"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

There is 2 joins (with folders) display only FOLDERS without VIDEO:

```
$dir = Directory::select('directory_relations.*','directory.*')->join('directory_relations', 'directory_relations.directory_id', '=', 'directory.id')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

There 3 joins (wtih folders+videos) display nothing:
    $dir = `Directory::select('directory_relations.*','directory.*','videos.*')->join('directory_relations', 'directory_relations.directory_id', '=', 'directory.id')->join('videos', 'directory_relations.video_id', '=', 'videos.id')->where('directory.user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();`

Comment: Please post your Eloquent Join Query...

Comment: added on bottom